# Prolog Average Rules

Tags: prolog, average

The following set of Prolog rules work on an input such as `average([3,4,5],A).`  Whereby `A = 4.0`.

However, if I try something like `average([3,4,X],4).` The following error is returned:

```
average([X|Xs],A) :- sum([X|Xs],S), length([X|Xs],L), {S/L=A}.

ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

How could I modify my code to allow `average([3,4,X],4)` to return the correct value for `X`?

Comment: If you use SWI-Prolog you can use library clpfd.

Comment: @joel76 how are you going to deal with the average of a list like `[3,4,4]` if you used library(clpfd)?

Comment: @boris : If there is only one free variable in the list you can write ***average(L, A) :-
 length(L, Len),
 sum(L, #=, Len * A).*** but I see now that there is a (big) problem with decimal numbers

Comment: @lurker: I suspect this is a clpq or clpr program. That is, `:- use_module(library(clpq)).` or `:- use_module(library(clpr)).` should be added. - rather clpr

Comment: @false thanks. I'm not familiar with those libraries.

Comment: @joel76: Why do you delete your answer? It is different in that the sum is calculated on the fly.

Comment: @false I'm satisfied of my answer because at the query ***average([1,X,Y], 4).*** I get the answer ***{Y=11-X, _G2233=1+X}.***

Comment: @joel76: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @false: I know it gives the relation between X and Y, but may be I use too much clpfd, where we can get all the solutions in a finite domain. I undelete my solution if you think it's usefull for the P.O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial solution with library(clpqr):

```
add(A, B, +(A,B)).
list_average([X|Xs], A) :-
    length([X|Xs], Len),
    foldl(add, Xs, X, Sum),
    {Sum =:= A*Len}.
```

If for some reason you don't want to use the library, you can try the following code.
This will probably solve your problem, but I am not happy with this code. Certainly someone else knows better:

```
list_average(L, A) :-
    (   is_list(L)
    ->  length(L, Len),
        term_variables(L-A, Vars),
        solve(Vars, L, A, Len)
    ;   instantiation_error(L)
    ).

solve([], L, A, Len) :-
    sum_list(L, Sum),
    A =:= Sum / Len. % Validate provided average
solve([X|Xs], L, A, Len) :-
    partition(number, L, Nums, Vars),
    length(Vars, T),
    sum_list(Nums, Sum),
    (   var(A)
    ->  maplist(=(A), Vars), % all variables are as the average
        A is Sum / (Len - T)
    ;   maplist(=(X), Xs), % all free variables in list are same
        X is (Len*A - Sum) / T
    ).
```

With this queries like this are possible:

```
?- list_average([2,3,4,5], A).
A = 3.5.

?- list_average([2,3,4,5], 3).
false.

?- list_average([2,X,4,5], 3).
X = 1.

?- list_average([2,X,4,Y], 3).
X = Y, Y = 3.

?- list_average([2,X,4,Y], A).
X = Y, Y = A, A = 3.

?- list_average([2,X,4,Y], 6).
X = Y, Y = 9.
```

It will automatically try to bind all free variables to a single free variable before solving numerically.

Comment: @false indeed, I see how much simpler everything is with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite the same as Boris solution, but I use library lambda :

```
:- use_module(library(clpr)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

average(L, A) :-
    length(L, Len),
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^{Z = X+Y}, L, 0, TT),
    {A * Len = TT}.
```

EDIT correction after false's remark.

Comment: `\X^Y^Z^{Z = X+Y}` is enough :-)